# Sending email with sendgrid [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

i'm using the following code to send two specific emails, one for the reservation client and other for me:

```
sendgrid.send({
        to:         "client@client.com",
        from:       "me@me.com",
        subject:    "Register confirmation",
        html:           "Some HTML",
    },
    function(err, json) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } 
        else {
            next();
        }
});

sendgrid.send({
        to:         "me@me.com",
        from:       "newRegister@me.com",
        subject:    "NEW RESERVATION!",
        html:       "SOME TEXT OR HTML",
    },
    function(err, json) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
        } 
        else {
            next();
        }
});
```

Can i improve this? There is some much duplication.

Comment: A wrapper is about all i can think of, that would manage the return of the promise and whatnot, something like send_message(params);

Comment: Sendgrid API V3 Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479562/2392211

Answer (score 2):

You could specify yourself as a recipient and you would get the exact email your client is receiving. If you use the [SMTPAPI](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/index.html), the user wouldn't see your email address and neither would you see theirs. To use that in the Node.js lib, you can do so this way:

```
var sendgrid = require('sendgrid')('api_user', 'api_pwd');
var email = sendgrid.Email();
email.smtpapi.addTo('client@email.com');
email.smtpapi.addTo('your@notification.email');
email.setSubject('Register confirmation');
email.setHtml('booking numbah');
email.setFrom('your@email.com');
sendgrid.send(email, function(err, json) {
   console.log(arguments);
});
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the **API key** you get from https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys. (Create API Key)

..and install @sendgrid/mail package of course.

> npm i @sendgrid/mail --save

```
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

const SENGRID_API_KEY = 'Here_Paste_Your_Key'; 
sgMail.setApiKey(SENGRID_API_KEY);

const msg = {
    to: 'to@email.com',
    from: 'from@email.com',
    subject: "Test Subject",
    text: 'Hello World!',
    html: '<strong>Hello World!</strong>',
};

sgMail.send(msg, function(err, info) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Email Not Sent.");
    } else {
        console.log("Email Sent Success.");
    }
});
```