# How to email multiple recipients in sendgrid v3 node.js

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid

Can someone help me send an email to multiple recipients in sendgrid v3 + node.js? I've noticed that when I enter several email addresses in the `to` field, only the first email address receives the email. The email addresses after the first one do not receive the email:

```
send: function(email, callback) {
    var from_email = new helper.Email(email.from);
    var to_email = new helper.Email('emailUser1@gmail.com,emailUser2@gmail.com,emailUser3@gmail.com');
    var subject = email.subject;
    var content = email.content
    var mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content);
    var sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
    var request = sg.emptyRequest({
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/v3/mail/send',
      body: mail.toJSON(),
    });

    sg.API(request, function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);
        if(err) {
            console.log('---error sending email:---');
            console.log(err);
            console.log(err.response.body);
            callback(500);
        } else {
            callback(200);
        }
    });

}
```

In the example above, only `emailUser1@gmail.com` receives the email; `emailUser2@gmail.com` and `emailUser3@gmail.com` do not receive the email.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJS Sendrgrid Issue in sending email to multiple recepients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455137/nodejs-sendrgrid-issue-in-sending-email-to-multiple-recepients)

Answer (score 18):

The node js mail helper allows you to send to multiple recipients by specifying the `to` property as an array. Then depending on whether you want the recipients to be able to see each other's addresses, you send the message in slightly different ways:

To allow seeing, use `sgMail.send(msg)`:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: ['recipient1@example.org', 'recipient2@example.org'],
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  subject: 'Hello world',
  text: 'Hello plain world!',
  html: '<p>Hello HTML world!</p>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

To prevent seeing, use `sgMail.sendMultiple(msg)` or `sgMail.send(msg, true)`

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: ['recipient1@example.org', 'recipient2@example.org'],
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  subject: 'Hello world',
  text: 'Hello plain world!',
  html: '<p>Hello HTML world!</p>',
};
sgMail.sendMultiple(msg);
```

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/b3b2092b7a150ffc5d68c9bb6575810a5827f69e/docs/use-cases/single-email-multiple-recipients.md

Under the covers the helper uses `Personalizations` which you can use for greater control:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations/

Answer (score 9):

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
module.exports.send = function () {
    sgMail.setApiKey('XYZ');
    const msg = {
        to: ['abc@gmal.com', 'xyz@gmail.com'],
        cc: ['test@gmail.com', 'testing@gmail.com'],
        from: 'no-reply@mail.total.fr',
        subject: 'Subject of mail',
        html: 'html body',
        text: 'text message'
    };
    // console.log('message in mail :: ', msg);
    sgMail.send(msg).catch(console.error);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "from": "sender@yourdomain.com",
  "template_id": "YOUR TEMPLATE ID",
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "john@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "send_at": 1600188812
    },
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "jane@example.com"
        }
      ],
      "send_at": 1600275471
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SendGrid's [Helper Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs)? You're going to want to leverage [Personalizations](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/personalizations/).

If you want the recipients to see each other, you should name & populate each of the recipients within a single Personalization object. If you don't want them to see each other, and want them to each receive the message distinctly, you'll want to make a new Personalization object for each distinct recipient group.

Comment: Yes, I'm using SendGrid's helper library - so you're saying that listing everyone's email in a single string wont work? such as: `to: email1@gmail.com; email2@gmail.com; email3@gmail.com`?

Comment: Correct. As a safety against someone accidentally sending `TO` everyone without meaning to, SendGrid doesn't build off the native To: header that way. They want you to use the Personalizations object, to that your intentions of recipient cross-visibility are clear.

Answer (score 0):

Sendgrid API V3

Hope this helps.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid-v3-node

Example:
https://runkit.com/embed/ne9asbfj59fr

```
var sendgrid = require("sendgrid-v3-node")

const mailOptions = {
    sendgrid_key: 'SENDGRID_KEY',
    from_email: 'FROM_EMAIL',
    from_name: 'FROM_NAME',
    to: ['TO_EMAIL1', 'TO_EMAIL2']
};

mailOptions.subject = 'SUBJECT';
mailOptions.content = 'CONTENT';
sendgrid.send_via_sendgrid(mailOptions).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
});
```