# Sendgrid v3 mail returns 202 but email doesn't send

Tags: node.js, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to send an email verification via Sendgrid to users who have signed up for the first. Following the v3_mail example found [here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v3_Mail/nodejs.html), I've created the following implementation:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');
const helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
const https = require('https');

const url = "http://<mywebsite.com>/users/reset/passwordLoggedOut?";
let sg = require('sendgrid')(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const emails = {};

function sendMail(mail){
    const request = sg.emptyRequest({
       method: 'POST',
       path: '/v3/mail/send',
       body: mail.toJSON(),
    });

    sg.API(request, function(error, response) {
       console.log(response.statusCode);
       console.log(response.body);
       console.log(response.headers);
       console.log(error);
    });
}

emails.sendActivationEmail = function(user){
     let qso = {username: user.username, activationCode: user.activationCode};
     let qs = querystring.stringify(qso);
     let from = new helper.Email('Thomas.Talhelm@chicagobooth.edu');
     let to = new helper.Email(user.username);
     let subject = 'Welcome to Psych Study \'16';
     let content = new helper.Content('text/html', "<p> Thanks for signing up " +
    "for our psych study, please <a href=\"http://<mywebsite.com>/users/validate/account?" + 
     qs + "\">confirm your email</a></p>");

     let mail = new helper.Mail(from, subject, to, content);

     sendMail(mail);

     console.log('Mail Sent!');
}

module.exports = emails;
```

Anytime I signup a user, these functions are eventually called without error, although I receive a status code of 202 (response received, email is queued for delivery), and the email never gets sent. The problem is somewhat similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214048/sendgrid-returns-202-but-doesnt-send-email), but my activity log is blank even though I've entered the SendGrid API properly by an environment variable which is well-defined. I've tried re-creating my API key, used full permissions on the key, and have not found an explanation for this behavior from the API.

Comment: Same problem here. I reported it to SendGrid's support because it occurred on a server that some weeks ago was working perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sendgrid returns 202 but doesn't send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42214048/sendgrid-returns-202-but-doesnt-send-email)

Comment: Sendgrid API V3 Hope that helps! https://stackoverflow.com/a/50479562/2392211

Comment: @NathanWailes why do you mark it duplicate , the answer you are pointing didn't help anyone and not any accepted answer

Comment: @MahaDev The *answers* to that question have no bearing on whether this question is a duplicate of that question.